# Does chrome have different functionality when starting from a maximized screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, window

I am getting strange functionality when loading from a maximized screen vs (1.non-max 2.to-max 3.back-to-non-max)(the latter currently works properly)

When starting from a maximized screen everything adjusts as it should except there is a big patch of empty space which isn't represented by any element when in the debugger.  This code is intended to have a top banner which is never less then 1000px wide and has a center container which is always 720px and should be centered.

```
var bodyColor = '#00004C';

var centerID = 'centerID';
var centerWidth = 970;
var centerMarginLeft = 0;
var centerColor = '#1947D1';
var centerHeight = 0;
var centerMinHeight = 900;

var topBarContainerMinWidth = 1000;
var topBarContainerHeight = 30;
var topBarContainerID = 'topBarContainer';
var topBarContainerWidth = 0;

var topCenterBarID = 'topBar';
var topCenterBarMarginLeft = 0;

window.onload = function () {
    $('body').css({ backgroundColor: bodyColor, marginLeft: '0px', marginTop: '0px', marginRight: '0px', marginBottom: '0px' });

    $('<div id=' + topBarContainerID + ' ></div>').appendTo('body').css({ height: topBarContainerHeight, float: 'left', backgroundColor: 'yellow' });
    topBar();

    $('<div id=' + centerID + ' ></div>').appendTo('body').css({ width: centerWidth, backgroundColor: centerColor, float: 'left' });
    centerContainer();

    $('<div id=' + topCenterBarID + ' ></div>').appendTo('#' + topBarContainerID).css({ backgroundColor: 'orange', float: 'left', height: '100%', width: centerWidth });
    topCenter();

    $('<div id="bottomPlaceHolder"></div>').appendTo('body').css({ width: topBarContainerWidth, height: topBarContainerHeight, float: 'left' });
}

window.onresize = function () {
    topBar();
    centerContainer();
    topCenter();
}

function topCenter() {
    topCenterBarMarginLeft = centerMarginLeft;
    $('#' + topCenterBarID).css({ marginLeft: topCenterBarMarginLeft });
}

function centerContainer() {
    centerMarginLeft = parseInt((topBarContainerWidth - centerWidth) / 2);
    centerHeight = $(window).height() - (topBarContainerHeight * 2);
    if (centerHeight < centerMinHeight)
        centerHeight = centerMinHeight;
    $('#' + centerID).css({ marginLeft: centerMarginLeft, height: centerHeight });
}

function topBar() {
    if ($(window).width() < topBarContainerMinWidth) {
        topBarContainerWidth = topBarContainerMinWidth;
    }
    else
        topBarContainerWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#' + topBarContainerID).css({ width: topBarContainerWidth });
}
```

Comment: Do you have any example page or screenshots? Would probably help to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Yes, link to a complete page please, so we will know we're all talking about the exact same HTML. Also, with maximized, do you mean maximized or full screen?